# the switch case block after final score is outputed, is not compiling

Tags: c#

it doesnt show the IQ result after the final score has been shown. please help. this is the full program...i used an arrow to show the switch block that refuses to compile

```
class Class1
{
    public static int attempt, sum, AptScore, GenScore, MathScore, EngScore, bonus, TotalScore, FinalScore, choice = 0;
    public static string ans;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

           int FinalCount, AptCount = 0, EngCount = 0, MathCount = 0, GenCount = 0;

           Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Salisbury University IQ Test game \n=====================================");
           Console.WriteLine();
           Console.WriteLine("How many times have you attempted this test?");
           attempt = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


           while (true)
           {
               if (attempt > 1)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine("You cannot take this test");
                   break;
               }

               while (true)
               {

                   FinalCount = AptCount + EngCount + MathCount + GenCount;
                   if (FinalCount < 4)
                   {

                       Console.WriteLine("Salisbury University IQ Test game \n========================================");
                       Console.WriteLine("Press \n1. Aptitude \n2. English. \n3. Math \n4. Gk \n5. Exit");
                       choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                       switch (choice)
                       {
                           case 1:
                               if (AptCount > 0)
                               {
                                   Console.WriteLine("THIS QUESTION HAS BEEN ATTEMPTED!!!");
                                   Console.WriteLine();
                                   continue;

                               }
                               Console.WriteLine(" What was the name of the lebanon tyrant who ruled for years unending before he was toppled due to civil war? \nA. Osama Bin laden \nB. Gaddafi \nC. Jonathan ");
                               ans = Console.ReadLine();
                               if (ans == "B" || ans == "b")
                               {
                                   AptScore += 10;
                               }
                               AptCount++;
                               continue;

                           case 2:
                               if (EngCount > 0)
                               {
                                   Console.WriteLine("THIS QUESTION HAS BEEN ATTEMPTED!!!");
                                   Console.WriteLine();
                                   continue;
                               }
                               Console.WriteLine(" What is the antonym of Pleasure? \nA. Pain \nB. Ecstacy \nC. Wonder");
                               ans = Console.ReadLine();
                               if (ans == "A" || ans == "a")
                               {
                                   EngScore += 10;
                               }
                               EngCount++;
                               continue;


                           case 3:
                               if (MathCount > 0)
                               {
                                   Console.WriteLine("THIS QUESTION HAS BEEN ATTEMPTED!!!");
                                   Console.WriteLine();
                                   continue;
                               }
                               Console.WriteLine(" What is the sum of 435 and 345? \nA. 799 \nB. 780 \nC. 600 ");
                               ans = Console.ReadLine();
                               if (ans == "B" || ans == "b")
                               {
                                   MathScore += 10;
                               }
                               MathCount++;
                               continue;

                           case 4:
                               if (GenCount > 0)
                               {
                                   Console.WriteLine("THIS QUESTION HAS BEEN ATTEMPTED!!!");
                                   Console.WriteLine();
                                   continue;
                               }
                               Console.WriteLine(" What year did Nigeria become a republic? \nA. 1960 \nB. 1963 \nC. 1990 ");
                               ans = Console.ReadLine();
                               if (ans == "B" || ans == "b")
                               {
                                   GenScore += 10;
                               }
                               GenCount++;
                               continue;

                           case 5:
                               Environment.Exit(0);
                               break;

                           default:
                               Console.WriteLine("You entered an invalid number");
                               continue;
                       } // end of switch

                   break;
               }  // end of inner while loop
                   break;
            } // end of else

              break;
           } // outer loop end

           if (attempt < 5 && attempt != 0)
           {
           TotalScore = MathScore + GenScore + EngScore + AptScore;
           Console.WriteLine("Your total score is : " + TotalScore);

           if (TotalScore == 10)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(" You have no Bonus point ");
           }
           else if (TotalScore == 20)
           {
               bonus += 2;
               Console.WriteLine("Your Bonus is {0}", bonus);
           }
           else if (TotalScore == 30)
           {
               bonus += 5;
               Console.WriteLine("Your Bonus is {0}", bonus);

           }
           else if (TotalScore == 40)
           {
               bonus += 10;
               Console.WriteLine("Your Bonus is {0}", bonus);

           }

            FinalScore = TotalScore + bonus;
               Console.WriteLine("Your finalscore is : " + FinalScore);

**it refuses to compile this switch block -->**  switch (FinalScore)
               {
                   case 10:
                       if (FinalScore >= 10)
                       {
                           Console.WriteLine("Your IQ level is below average");
                       }
                       break;

                   case 22:
                       if (FinalScore >= 22)
                       {
                           Console.WriteLine("Your IQ level is average");
                       }
                       break;
                   case 35:
                       if (FinalScore >= 35)
                       {
                           Console.WriteLine("You are intelligent");
                       }
                       break;
                   case 40:
                       if (FinalScore == 40)
                       {
                           Console.WriteLine("You are a genius");
                       }
                       break;

                   default:
                       break;

               } // end of last s1witch case

           }// end of if statement
       } // end of main method */


    } // end of class
```

Comment: What error does it say?

Comment: `case 22` will only match on *exactly* 22. So doing `if (FinalScore >= 22)` inside that case is pointless. Your switch block only handles the exact scored 10, 22, 35 and 40. Just get rid of that switch, and turn the `if`s into `else if`s (besides the first one, obviously.

Comment: What do you mean by _compile_?  This code compiles (short of your note pointing out the "bad" line).

Answer (score 1):

Its always better to use if/else for your particular case, With switch statement you can't put conditions in the case. It looks like you are checking for ranges and if the range is constant then you can try the following

```
                   if (FinalScore == 40)
                   {

                       Console.WriteLine("You are a genius");
                   }else  if (FinalScore >= 35)
                   {
                       Console.WriteLine("You are intelligent");

                   }else if (FinalScore >= 22)
                   {
                       Console.WriteLine("Your IQ level is average");

                   }else if(FinalScore >= 10)
                   {
                       Console.WriteLine("Your IQ level is below average");         
                   }else
                   {
                       // something else
                   }
```

Comment: top if should be `>=`

Comment: There are only 5 possible FinalScores (0, 10, 22, 35, 50).  Using the switch is fine; it's the cases that are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You should use If else statements for what you are trying to do and you could shorten your code a whole lot by making use of ternary statements like so,

```
 Console.WriteLine((FinalScore >= 40) ? "You are a genius" :
                 (FinalScore >= 35) ? "You are intelligent" :
                 (FinalScore >= 22) ? "Your IQ level is average" :
                 (FinalScore >= 10) ? "Your IQ level is below average" : "You are really below average");
//The really below average would be your something else referenced above.
```

Comment: There are only 5 possible FinalScores (0, 10, 22, 35, 50). Using the switch is fine; it's the cases that are wrong

Comment: Having finite scores that would be the case but that could potentially grow your switch statement quite large if more questions are introduced and more finite scores become an option.  It seems like with the greater than he was thinking of some type of range scoring which would mean he would need to use if else statements to logically step through scoring.

Answer (score 0):

Your code compiles just fine.

If you logged the default case of that switch block, you would've seen that 40 is effectively an unreachable case.  Your formula guarantees that 40 is never generated -- all 4 correct is 50 points due to the bonus points.  All incorrect would also never yield a result.

The valid cases are:  `0, 10, 22, 35, 50`.  You only account for `10, 22, & 35`.

```
default:
    // this would've thrown an exception for FinalScore==50
    throw new Exception("unexpected score of " + FinalScore);
```